# Google Compute Engine automation with C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I want to automate my operation in Google's cloud.

4 tasks I would like to achieve:

1. Get list of all my VMs.
2. Stop specific VM.
3. Delete specific VM.
4. Create a VM from image.

My code (written with C#) should be able to run those functions to manage the cloud resources.

Is this possible to do with Google cloud?

I'm know that this is possible with Microsoft-Azure (Azure Power Shell). What the equivalent in Google Cloud?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Google API Client library for .NET](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) (see also some non-cloud-specific [code samples](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples)) to access all Google services for developers, including Google Cloud Platform.

Follow the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) to set up your environment with authentication, etc. Then see the [docs for Google Compute Engine .NET client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/compute/v1).